# Checking specific list entry and the rest of the list entries

Tags: python, list, loops, tkinter, multidimensional-array

Im making a sudoku game and I need to be able to check if the entered number is already in the row or already in the column for a conflict. Right now this is changing the background of all of the seed values. How do I check for a specific entry and see if it is in either the row or the columns already?

```
  #nums_list is a 2_d list of the Entry widget id tags
  #check_list are the 0's and digits of the seed values
  def check_conf(self):
    for r in range(0, self.height, 1):
        for c in range(0, self.width, 1):
            if self.nums_list[r][c].get().isdigit():
                if int(self.nums_list[r][c].get()) == int(self.check_list[r][c]):
                    self.nums_list[r][c].config(background = 'red')
```

full code at http://pastebin.com/Mmmh6JM4

Comment: what is `.get()` doing?

Comment: Im using a 9 x 9 grid of Entry widgets in tkinter .get() is getting the value of what is inside the entry widget

Comment: why do you need cast to int to compare? Not fully sure what your code is doing but storing possible positions in a dict as tuples may be easier

Comment: Is the code you posted working?

Comment: Ah youre right int() is redundant since Im already checking if its an integer, and no its highlighting all of the given values not checking if there is duplicates in rows or columns thats the issue Im having and trying to fix

Comment: I figured it out I'm checking if the file's seed values are equal to those entries which is obviously true. I need to create a new list of all of the current entries and check if the new entry is already in that specific row or column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Glad you figured it out.

I'll risk downvotes for this comment in an answer: You could make your code a bit more readable if you did something like this:

```
#nums_list is a 2_d list of the Entry widget id tags
#check_list are the 0's and digits of the seed values
def check_conf(self):
    # iterate over rows
    for widgets, check_values in zip(self.nums_list, self.check_list):
        #iterate over columns
        for widget, check_value in zip(widgets, check_values):
            if widget.get().isdigit():
                if widget.get() == check_value:
                    widget.config(background = 'red')
```

Comment: Are the typoes (widg**e**t, not widgit) intentional?

Comment: @badp ... just not paying attention to my names, thnx for pointing it out.